# Разработка Andriod приложения в Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Скрин самой проблемы:

[image: Скрин самой проблемы:]

Создавал проект по книге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не подключена библиотека AppCompat. с ней в эклипсе геморно, задача не для новичка. проще удалить все файлы styles и в манифесте на что будет ругаться (аттрибут theme) удалить

Comment: лучше в android studio пишите, если железо позволит.

Comment: Rou1997 спасибо ответ, сейчас попробую удалить theme, а как подключить AppCompact?

Comment: добыть его код (в Android SDK где-то шел или градлом вручную скачать) и собрать как library project. затем в список библиотек Вашего проекта (именно на вкладке Android) добавить этот проект. нужен именно код целиком, а не только jar, иначе работать не будет. подробностей не помню, 5 мес проект тот простаивает, сейчас с совсем другими ОС работаю. помню что нюансов много в эклипсе, например, compile sdk версия должна быть высокой (21, 23, 25) и в проекте либы и в том который ее использует.

Comment: Теперь буду хотя-бы знать в чём именно состоит проблема, спасибо

Comment: @Виктор, книгу вам бы поновее... За 3 года всё поменялось и она не очень актуальна, мягко говоря. И да - Eclipse более не поддерживается гуглом и у вас на каждом шаге будут практически нерешаемые проблемы. Переходите на AndroidStudio, тем более, что она в разы лучше Eclipse

Comment: У этой книги есть более свежие издания, 2016 и даже 2017 годов. Первая точно есть в свободном доступе в интернете. В этих изданиях описывается разработка в Android Studio. Так что лучше обновите Ваше издание и не мучайтесь с Eclipse, ибо это бесперспективно.